# Docker run command failing when trying to install the mysql php extension

Tags: php, python, mysql, docker

I have a docker php container that I need to connect to a mysql container, in order to do so I use the following docker file to construct the appropriate image:

```
FROM php:7-fpm
ADD /build /build
ADD /config /config
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

I have written a python script to automate the process of building and running my containers, in particular it executes these functions to build the php container image:

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
php_image = client.images.build(path="./php-docker/",tag="bjaniston/php-container",rm=True)
```

Up until recently this was working absolutely fine, but has now started failing with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker_setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    php_image = client.images.build(path="./php-docker/",tag="bjaniston/php-container",rm=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/docker/models/images.py", line 172, in build
    raise BuildError(chunk['error'])
docker.errors.BuildError: The command '/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install mysqli' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I am not sure what would cause this error, I have not modified the docker file since the last time this image was successfully built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the build command manually in the terminal docker gave a different error saying that the device had run out of space, having browsed the docker forums to decipher the error I stumbled across this page:
https://forums.docker.com/t/where-does-docker-keep-images-containers-so-i-can-better-track-my-disk-usage/8370/9

Running the shell command below solved my problem (bear in mind this removes all named volumes from the host):

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q )
```

The original error from the docker python API seemed very opaque, and gave little idea of the cause of the problem.

Comment: I would clarify that that command remove all named volumes in the docker host.